# how to find the neighbors between nodes in python

Tags: python, list

```
o 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 0 
4 1
5 3
```

I have two node lists which shown above
how can i find the neighbors of each node and output can be shown as [[1, 4], [0, 2, 4], [1, 3], [2, 4, 5], [0, 1, 3], [3]]

Comment: As written the problem is ill-defined and not solvable.

Comment: Apparently the output is a list of immediate neighbour lists for the index within the outer list, and the input is a list of neighbouring pairs. aks somehow figured it out, but it was far from obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# nodes <infile
#
# Read in lists of node neighbors, and output complete list of all neighbors
#
# nodeA nodeB
# nodeC nodeD

class NodeList:
  def __init__(self):
    self.nodes = {}
    self.groups = 0

  def add_pair(self, n1, n2):       # add a pair of nodes
    self.add_node(n1, n2)           # they are neighbors
    self.add_node(n2, n1)           # to each other

  def add_node(self, n1, n2):
    if n1 not in self.nodes:
      self.nodes[n1] = []
    if n2 not in self.nodes[n1]:    # add n2 only if not already a link
      self.nodes[n1].append(n2)
      self.groups += 1

  def neighbors(self):
    return list(map(lambda k: sorted(self.nodes[k]), sorted(self.nodes.keys())))

nodes = NodeList()
while True:
  try:
    line = input()
    nums = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
    if len(nums) > 0:
      n1 = nums.pop(0)
      for nx in nums:
        nodes.add_pair(n1, nx)
  except EOFError:
    break

print(nodes.neighbors())

exit
```

The data file:

```
$ cat in-nodes
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 0
4 1
5 3
```

The run:

```
$ ./nodes.py <in-nodes
[[1, 4], [0, 2, 4], [1, 3], [2, 4, 5], [0, 1, 3], [3]]
```